# Slow boot time after changeover from Ubuntu to elementary OS

Tags: boot, swap

i'm a absolute beginner in Linux so i apologize in advance for my question.

First of all I decided to switch from Windows 10 to Ubuntu. After that I tried the elementary OS distribution, which is in my opinion designed absolute beautiful.

Now, I have a problem with the boot time. After the changeover from Ubuntu to elementary OS the boot process is really slow. So after pressing the start bottom there's at first a black screen for some seconds and then appears the elementary OS logo and I don't know why I have this black screen. I already read something about a wrong UUID for the swap partition, but I have no idea how I can find out the problem or change them.

Maybe this terminal--output is helpful:

`<file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
 / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=1c5c8b29-e843-46ab-9115-ab0245414bf6 / ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0`

For help or suggestions, I would be really grateful.

Comment: Please provide the output of: `systemd-analyze time`  `systemd-analyze blame | head -n 20`  `systemd-analyze critical-chain`  `sudo blkid`. And post also the complete content of fstab file (in /etc/fstab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long boot time can be caused by a lot of things.

In first place you should check *systemd journal* (systemd is operating system initialization program) by using `journalctl -b` command, which will show last system boot log.

Then you can scroll down and look at the timestamps to determine which process takes long time to be completed.